# Grails: Can't download dependencies due to "failed to canonicalize path" error

Tags: windows, maven, grails

We have a working Grails app that builds fine on Mac OSX and Linux. Dependencies are downloaded fine from our company's artifactory repository.

When we tried to set the app up on Windows 10 we get resolution errors we've never seen before:

```
[main] WARN org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultUpdateCheckManager - Failed to canonicalize path C:\%user_home%\.m2\repository\org\grails\plugins\yesmam\0.1-SNAPSHOT\maven-metadata-http:\[redacted]\artifactory\resolver-status.properties: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect
Error |
[main] WARN org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultUpdateCheckManager - Failed to create parent directories for tracking file C:\%user_home%\.m2\repository\org\grails\plugins\yesmam\0.1-SNAPSHOT\maven-metadata-http:\[redacted]\artifactory\resolver-status.properties
Error |
```

Note that the path shown in the error has the URL of our artifactory instance embedded within it, creating an invalid path.

Can anyone shed some light on this? This is Grails 2.5.2

Dan